# importing in python and checking __name__

Tags: python

I am importing a module (i am using its name as module only). Whenever i press

```
module.__name__
```

it is showing some name Module.module

when i did

```
print module
```

,i go to the path mentioned. I don't have the module, it has a pyd file. I am completely confused about python importing process,What exactly is `__name__`? How does change in `__name__` change the way we import, how does main change while importing

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several different questions here.  `__name__` is the name of the module, including any packages from which it was imported.  For the `__main__` issue, see the link Blender provided.  I don't understand what you mean by "change in `__name__` changes the way we import".

As for the .pyd file, that is a Python extension written in C.  It is basically a DLL that can be imported as a Python module.  You can use it from Python, but it's not written in Python.

Comment: e.g., relative imports use `__name__` to find where the module is in package hierarchy i.e., by changing `__name__` you can change what get imported though it is unlikely that OP means exactly that.

Comment: change in __name__ i mean now i can use modules by the name printed out when "module.__name__" is pressed  though there is no module by that name

Comment: if __name__ is the name of the module when i do module.__name__ why is it showing Module.module but not just the name by which i imported it with

Comment: @user1869634: `print module` doesn't print `.__name__` it prints module object itself (its representation as a string) that probably includes its type, name, filename.